# Authenticating while connecting to multiple database using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have set up auth in my MongoDB as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). Initially, in my project I was accessing a single database say, `firstdb` from mongoose using

```
let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/firstdb";
let options = {
    server:{
        socketOptions:{
            keepAlive:120
        }
    },
    user:"username1",
    pass:"mypassword1"
};
mongoose.connect(url,options,callback);
```

The user with `username` and `mypassword` was created in the `firstdb` itself giving it `readWrite` perms. I did this while logged in with my admin user.

Things were working smoothly. Then I had a requirement of connecting to a second database. So I changed my code as such

```
let url1 = "mongodb://localhost:27017/firstdb";
let options1 = {
    server:{
        socketOptions:{
            keepAlive:120
        }
    },
    user:"username1",
    pass:"mypassword1",
    auth:{
        authdb:"firstdb"
    }
};
let connection1 = mongoose.createConnection(url1,options1);

let url2 = "mongodb://localhost:27017/seconddb";
let options2 = {
    server:{
        socketOptions:{
            keepAlive:120
        }
    },
    user:"username2",
    pass:"mypassword2",
    auth:{
        authdb:"seconddb"
    }
};
let connection2 = mongoose.createConnection(url2,options2);
```

This time I created user `username2` the same way in the `seconddb` database. But now mongoose is unable to perform any operation and is failing with `Not authorized to execute command`. I can access the db through mongo shell though. I also spun up the code in my local system which doesn't have mongodb auth enabled and it works fine there. Please help

Answer (score 0):

So, after shooting around in the blind, found something that works.
Use the username and password in the url itself like

```
let connection1 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://username1:password1@localhost:27017/firstdb");
```

Still, I would like to know why passing the parameters as options doesn't work.